# JS Form Validator

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I use js form validator to write it.

Below is my code:

```
frmvalidator.addValidation("password","regexp=[a-zA-Z0-9!#$@_+,]{5,15}",  "Invalid password format.");
```

After that, I go to browser and type the following in password field:

- `test 123!#$@`              --> Invalid password format
- `test 123!#$@_+`          --> Invalid password format
- `test 123!#$@_+,`        --> No show error messages

I really don't understand why the third one is success without any error messages although I put the space between them. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: That was right. Your reg expression was matched with string

Comment: I don't understand why you don't get the same result for each string(all strings match).

Comment: Can you post a JS snippet/fiddle?